# Bash script to delete and match folder names to partial file names in different directories

Tags: bash, shell, compare, pattern-matching

[EDIT] Problem solved. Script updated below. Thanks to everyone for the help. Had a few mods i needed to do to make it all work with spaces in folder names and non empty folders.

Really having a hard time with this one.

When a file is downloaded, my system creates two things:

1. a file (created in my "Jobs" directory), e.g.

   - Johns.Pizza.Place.5489231.job
   - Marks.Hair.Salon.NY.888.job
   - Rachels.Bike.and.Boat.Shop.11122287865.job
2. a folder with the name of the file (created in my "Temp" directory), e.g.

   - Johns.Pizza.Place
   - Marks.Hair.Salon.NY
   - Rachels.Bike.and.Boat.Shop

As you can see, the folder names always match part of the filenames but each file is always appended with a random number of length and then the extension (which is '.job').

What I want to do is be able to run a script that tries to

1. Match the the folder names in the directory of files BUT is only doing a partial match since the files have both a random number and extension added, then
2. Deletes those folders when it DOES NOT FIND an associated file (I am using Hazel to delete the files after certain actions). If a matching files is found for a folder, I don't want that folder deleted.

Here is what I tried but I know it's incomplete. Obviously I'm trying to pull just folder name in path to match with partial filenames where I have removed the extension but I am not sure how to also remove the random number string.

[EDIT]: Final working script below

```
#! /bin/sh

MainDir="/Users/Dhy/Desktop/Temp Files/1. All Files/"
JobDir="/Users/Dhy/Documents/All Jobs/"                             

find "$MainDir"* -maxdepth 0 -type d | while read FolderName; do
SuffixName=$(basename "${FolderName}");
    preserve=''
    for file in "$JobDir"*.job; do
        if [[ $file\.[0-9]+ =~ $SuffixName ]]; then 
            preserve='on'
        break 
        fi
    done

    if [ -z $preserve ]; then
        rm -rf "$MainDir$SuffixName"
    fi
done
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` because `[[ ]]` is not supported in `sh`. It's possible that `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash` but it's better to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for Dir in $(find $MainDir* -maxdepth 0 -type d ); do
    FolderName=$(basename $Dir);
    cd /Users/Dhy/Documents/Jobs
    if [ -z "$(find . -regex "\./$FolderName\.[0-9]*\.job")" ]
         rmdir "$FolderName"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I feel like its close but the blanket find command is essentially finding the folder names themselves as matches and thus deleting every time. What I need is for the "Find" to be searching for the names of the folders that are stored in the "temp" directory matching against filenames of the files in a different directory, the "jobs" directory.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to place the `cd` command =/. Would that fix the problem?

Comment: Hmm. No. Seems that the find is not obeying to the cd folder and instead still checking upon itself thus is always returns true. Must be a different way to run that if statement on just the second directory...but havent been able to figure it out.

Comment: `find` will always return true (AFAIK), but the string generated by its output shouldn't be empty (we test with the `-z` flag). If it still doesn't work, next try is to hardcode the dir: `if [ -z "$(find /Users/Dhy/Documents/Jobs -regex "/Users/Dhy/Documents/Jobs/$FolderName\.[0-9]*\.job")" ]`

Comment: First, Janito, thank you for your patience. I tried your suggestion, and it still seems not to work. Two comments. 1) I added a "then" to the end of the if statement and i also am using an echo command just to test instead of the rmdir. I am using one filename and foldername that match and then I have another folder that does not have an associated file. Yet, as the script runs through, both foldernames are saying they are matched even though there isnt a corresponding file with the same foldername in the other directory.

Comment: I did. I also did some further testing with that script you provided. From what I can tell, the if and find have no bearing on the next statement. What i mean is, if you just hardcode the path and value so that you would be searching for one specific file, it still doesnt return the right answer. I made FolderName equal to "Pizza" and then searched for the file Pizza.job (even though the only file in the folder was Test.job) and it still returned a positive result, suggesting to me that the script is still looking into either the wrong folder or all folders.

Comment: It's working here on my PC. Don't know if it could be a consequence of `bash` or `find` version. Try executing `find . -regex "\./ExistentDir\.[0-9]*\.job"` to see if it prints out the "ExistentDir" directory (must change it to a directory that actually exists). The if is succeeding because `find` is printing out any matches. This is the expected behaviour for directories that don't exist, but it should print out the name of an existent directory when it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of %% is deleting everything after the first dot, not the last one.  Something like this will probably be the transform you want:

```
name="${file%.*.job}"
```

The % operator is non-greedy, so it will select the shortest matching string to remove.

Comment: Thanks Brian. But Still having an issue including that in my script. Would I not then use the: 'for file in *.job; do' section?

Comment: That was meant as a replacement for the existing name= statement; nothing else in the script should change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that the actual filename does not contain numbers, you can replace `name=${file%%[.]*}` with `name=${file%%.[0-9]*}`.

Also in your current script, you remove the directory as soon as the first `name` don't match `FolderName`. The correct way to do it is to check that all `name`s don't match, i.e. remove directory only after the inner for loop ends. If there's a match, set a flag (in the case below, a non-empty string) to prevent the directory from being removed.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
#!/bin/bash

MainDir="/Users/Dhy/Desktop/Temp/"
JobDir="/Users/Dhy/Documents/Jobs/"

for Dir in $(find $MainDir* -maxdepth 0 -type d ); do
    FolderName=$(basename $Dir);
    preserve=''
    for file in $JobDir*.job; do
        if [[ $file =~ $FolderName\.[0-9]+ ]]; then 
            preserve='on'
            break 
        fi
    done

    if [ -z $preserve ]; then
       rmdir $MainDir$FolderName
    fi
done
```

p/s: `.` is not a special character in parameter expansion, so you can use it without the square brackets.

p/s2: You don't need `cd` here, you can simply append the path to `*`

Comment: Thanks DD. This makes sense to me as i do need to have the first folder checked against all file names. I tried your script but am still having the same problem. All folders are being deleted even if there is a corresponding file with the same filename just with the .job extension. For some reason, the match of FolderName to the filename is either not happening or is being ignored. So odd.

Comment: Awww made a serious typo... I forgot to use the `name=${file%%.[0-9]*}` that I proposed. Does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt. I have tried a bunch of different permutations but nothing yet working.

Comment: Once again, I missed a `then` after `if [ -z $preserve ]`... not sure if it changes anything...

Comment: Actually I found out what the problem was: `$JobDir` was appended to the filename in the inner for loop, so the `$FolderName` and `$file` never matched. Anyway this edited version should hopefully work now.

Comment: This worked! I just had to swap the "\.[0-9]+" to the $file side. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey DD, One of my directories has spaces in the name and this causes the script to go FUBAR. I tried entering the path with spaces in the MainDir variable and then putting "$MainDir" but that didnt work. I tried using the path directly without any variables and still no dice. I think the spaces combined with the loop using the "*" is causing issues. Do you have an idea how to solve it? Thanks again as otherwise the script is perfect.

Comment: I have figured it out after much trial and error. I have modified my orignal post with the updated script. Much thanks.

Comment: There's a reason why I used this `$file =~ $FolderName\.[0-9]+`, say your `$file` is `Johns.Pizza.Place.5489231.job`, this would match `Johns.Pizza.Place`, but *not* `Johns.Pizza.Place.Actually.Mikes.Place`. I'm not sure why this doesn't work for you, and I'm not sure if `[0-9]+` being on `$file`'s side actually does anything. I'm gonna do some testing...

Comment: Just checked and mine works as intended (when foldernames do not contain spaces).